# Scatter plot over seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

I'm trying to mark a position (in this case the minimum value along the colormap axis) on a seaborn heatmap. But the position I want to mark falls in between values on heatmap since it is discrete and plotted at a lower resolution than the original dataframe. I have a feeling I just need to use the same axes to overplot properly but I can't seem to find anything that works! Instead, my scatterplot point either always appears in the lower left-hand corner or doesn't appear at all.

So -- how can I plot a symbol representing the minimum value in my original, higher resolution dataframe over this lower resolution heatmap?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

number_of_planes = 100

cos_thetas = np.empty(number_of_planes)
phis = np.empty(number_of_planes)
for i in range(0,number_of_planes):
    phi = np.random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
    theta = math.acos(2*np.random.uniform(0.5,1) - 1)

    phis[i] = phi
    cos_thetas[i] = math.cos(theta)

thicknesses = np.random.rand(number_of_planes, number_of_planes)

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

thick_df = pd.DataFrame(thicknesses*1000, columns=phis, index=cos_thetas)

#print thick_df

thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=False)
thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=1)

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(start=2.9, light=0.9, as_cmap=True, reverse=True)

yticks = np.linspace(0,1,6)

x_end = 6
xticks = np.arange(x_end+1)

m, n = 10, 10
row_groups = np.arange(len(thick_df.index)) // m
col_groups = np.arange(len(thick_df.columns)) // n

grpd = pd.DataFrame(thick_df.values, row_groups, col_groups)

val = pd.to_numeric(grpd.stack(), 'coerce').groupby(level=[0, 1]).mean().unstack().values
idx = thick_df.index.to_series().groupby(row_groups).mean().values
col = thick_df.columns.to_series().groupby(col_groups).mean().values

new_thick_df = pd.DataFrame(val, idx, col)

sns.heatmap(new_thick_df, linewidth=0, xticklabels=xticks, yticklabels=yticks[::-1], square=True, cmap=cmap, ax=ax)
#new_thick_df.plot.scatter(thick_df.columns.argmin(), thick_df.index.argmin(), ax=ax, c='r', s=100)
#One problem here is that thick_df.columns.argmin() gives an integer position instead of the column label
ax.scatter(thick_df.columns.argmin(), thick_df.index.argmin(), marker='*', s=100, color='yellow')  

ax.set_xticks(xticks*ax.get_xlim()[1]/(2*math.pi))
ax.set_yticks(yticks*ax.get_ylim()[1])
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\rm{\phi}$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\rm{\cos\ \theta}$', fontsize=16)
plt.figtext(0.865, 0.5, r'$\rm{thickness\ (kpc)}$', fontsize=15, rotation=270, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Since you sorted the index of your thick_df your `thick_df.columns.argmin()` and  `thick_df.index.argmin()` will always be 0 and 99. You x/y range for your plot is 0-10 for both axis. And did you mean to use `new_thick_df` in draw the star in the scatter plot? This will still always yield 0,9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you just want to plot a star from the absolute minimum value of `thick_df`. You have averaged every 10x10 section of `thick_df` into a `new_thick_df`. The heatmap is created from `new_thick_df` but you would like to plot the minimum from `thick_df` onto this heatmap. You will have to first find the minimum by flattening `thick_df` and then reducing the dimensions so that they are converted to a range between 0 and 10. I have also plotted a red star for the min for the `new_thick_df`.

Change this line: `ax.scatter(thick_df.columns.argmin(), thick_df.index.argmin(), marker='*', s=100, color='yellow')` to these lines

```
idx_min_big = thick_df.values.flatten().argmin()
x_min_big, y_min_big = (idx_min_big % 100) / 10 , 10 - (idx_min_big // 100) / 10
ax.scatter(x_min_big, y_min_big, marker='*', s=100, color='yellow') 

# get min of new_thick_df
min_idx = new_thick_df.values.flatten().argmin()
x_min, y_min = min_idx % 10 + .5, 9 - min_idx // 10 + .5
ax.scatter(x_min, y_min, marker='*', s=100, color='yellow')
```

[image]

And just to prove that the minimum of `thick_df` works with this logic

```
x,y = idx_min_big // 100, idx_min_big % 100    
thick_df.iloc[x, y]
```

Output

```
0.075901121550980832
```

Get the minimum

```
thick_df.values.flatten().min()
```

Output

```
0.075901121550980832
```

Comment: But I'm not wondering where cos_theta and phi are minimized, I'm wondering where the thickness is smallest. So what I need is to plot a cos_theta and phi value corresponding to the smallest element in the dataframe. I actually did mean thick_df instead of new_thick_df above because I want the higher resolution minimum from the original dataframe plotted over the lower resolution dataframe.

Comment: OK, but the sorting makes no sense. It will always yield 0, 99. Get rid of the sorting and just divide by 10. See updated answer

Comment: Or more generally, to plot any specific value that lies between the values of the squares on my heatmap.

Comment: No, the sorting does make sense because that's what makes the axis labels for phi and cos_theta correct. I'm not trying to get the minimum of phi and cos_theta so there's no reason it should always be 0,99.

Comment: I don't actually think that argmin is the right function for this but I can't find one that is.

Comment: Updated answer to get argument min of sum of rows or columns

Comment: Why the sum? I just want the index and column of the minimum element. A correct answer will put the point somewhere (not necessarily centered) in the darkest square. Sorry -- I know you're trying to help but I feel like you don't quite understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Ok i updated the answer. It will put a star in the center of the darkest square. I use new_thick_df to get the darkest square. If you use thick_df, the minimum will correspond to a number in (0,99) for both x and y. You can of course divide this by 10 but it's not likely that it will match the minimum for the entire group.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like you still don't understand so let's just let it go. Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: I just added a picture that shows my answer. Please look at it. It always plots a star in the center of the darkest square as you said.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are saying. You want the min of the larger data frame (`thick_df`) - this won't correspond at all to the min of the `new_thick_df`. I'll plot both stars in just a few minutes.

Comment: Right, but I need to make 94 of these plots. I'm not trying to manually put a star on the center of the darkest square. That's not accurately representing the minimum.

Comment: Please check the updated solution. I believe it gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: This appears to work for my MWE. Thank you! In my actual code I had another way to retrieve the cos_theta and phi values corresponding to the minimum thickness so I assigned that and used the following: `ax.scatter(thinnest_phi/max(xticks)*n, thinnest_cos_theta/max(yticks)*n, marker='*', s=100, color='red')`. In other words, I found the fractional values of cos_theta and phi corresponding to the minimum thickness and then multiplied by the number of cells along each axis of the plotted dataframe to scale that up properly.